# Strange Promise.all behaviour

Tags: node.js, promise

In one file called SearchBuilder.js i have this function ( wrote in this way as pure test )

```
self.validateInputs = async params => {
        const validateDates = async () => {
            const pick_up_date = moment(`${params.pick_up_date} ${params.pick_up_time}`),
                drop_off_date = moment(`${params.drop_off_date} ${params.drop_off_date}`);
                return true;
        };
        const validatePickUpId = async () => {
            return true;
        };
        const validateDropOffId = async () => {
            throw { 'code': 'NOT_FOUND'};
        };

        return Promise.all([
            validateDates,
            validatePickUpId,
            validateDropOffId,
        ]);
    };
```

In another file called searchEngine.js i have this:

```
self.run = async (type, search_inputs, account) => {
        const searchBuilder  = self.getSearchBuilder(type);
        try {
            const isValid = await searchBuilder.validateInputs(search_inputs);
            console.log(isValid);
        } catch (e) {
            console.log('error input validation');
        }

        return search;
    };
```

I erroneously thought that if any of the promises in Promise.all would fail, so my code will enter the catch block. Instead, even if the promise fails code inside the catch is never executed and inside isValid i get this.

```
[ [AsyncFunction: validateDates],
  [AsyncFunction: validatePickUpId],
  [AsyncFunction: validateDropOffId] ]
```

Comment: `Promise.all` expects an array of promises, you're passing an array of functions.

Comment: Why are you using promises and `async` functions at all? Your entire code could be synchronous.

Comment: well, as this is just a test code it's synchronous but with the real code inside it would be async. thanks for your feedback